# what does $^S mean in perl?

Tags: perl

What does $^S mean in perl?
looking at https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar all I can find is

> Having to even think about the $^S variable in your exception handlers
> is simply wrong.

```
perl -e 'print qq|What does "\$^S":$^S mean in perl?\n Thank you\n|'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar) actually says the following for [`$^S`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5ES):

> Current state of the interpreter.
>
> ```
> $^S         State
> ---------   -------------------------------------
> undef       Parsing module, eval, or main program
> true (1)    Executing an eval or try block
> false (0)   Otherwise
> ```
>
> The first state may happen in `$SIG{__DIE__}` and `$SIG{__WARN__}` handlers.

Say you want to decorate exceptions with a timestamp, but only those that aren't caught to avoid breaking anything or having multiple timestamps added.

```
$ perl -e'
   use POSIX qw( strftime );

   # Decorate error messages, part 1.
   local $SIG{ __DIE__ } = sub {
      # Avoid exiting prematurely.
      return if $^S;

      my $ts = strftime( "%FT%TZ", gmtime() );
      print( STDERR "[$ts] $_[0]" );
      exit( $! || $? >> 8 || 255 );
   };

   # Decorate error messages, part 2.
   local $SIG{ __WARN__ } = sub {
      # Avoid mangling exceptions that are being handled.
      return if $^S;

      my $ts = strftime( "%FT%TZ", gmtime() );
      print( STDERR "[$ts] $_[0]" );
   };

   eval {
      die( "Some caught exception\n" );
   };
   if ( $@ ) {
      warn( "Caught: $@" );
   }

   die( "Some uncaught exception\n" );
'
[2022-12-15T05:57:44Z] Caught: Some caught exception
[2022-12-15T05:57:44Z] Some uncaught exception
```

Without checking `$^S`, we would have exited prematurely.

Comment: Thanks I was looking at perlvar for a while and for some reason was not finding that even with 'find in page'. I presumed the $^ letters were in alphabetical order in the doc. Great example. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit [further down](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5ES) on `perlvar`.

> Current state of the interpreter.
>
> ```
> $^S         State
> ---------   -------------------------------------
> undef       Parsing module, eval, or main program
> true (1)    Executing an eval or try block
> false (0)   Otherwise
> ```

Confusingly, the variable's full `use English` name is `$EXCEPTIONS_BEING_CAUGHT`, despite, as the documentation goes on to admit, the fact that the variable really doesn't inform you as to whether or not an exception is being caught.

Comment: Re "*the variable really doesn't inform you as to whether or not an exception is being caught*", That's exactly what it does ...when used in `$SIG{ __DIE__ }`. Which is the only place where it makes sense to use `$^S`.